# Marcus Number Fields Chapter 4 Exercise 6

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Can you give any hint on this problem.

6. Let $m$ and $n$ be distinct squarefree integers $\neq1$. The biquadratic field $K =
   \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{m}, \sqrt{n}]$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group isomorphic to the Klein
   $4$-group (direct sum of two cyclic groups of order $2$). Thus there are three quadratic
   subfields (what is the third?). Let $p$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.

1. Suppose $p$ is ramified in each of the quadratic subfields. What happens in $K$?
   Find an example.
2. Suppose $p$ splits completely in each of the quadratic subfields. What happens in
   $K$? Find an example.
3. Suppose $p$ is inert in each of the quadratic subfields. What happens in $K$? Can
   this ever occur?
4. Find an example in which $p$ splits into $P$ $Q$ in $K$; $P^2Q^2$; $P^2$

So far I have worked on $1)$ but I am confused, If $p$ is ramified in an intermediate field doesn't mean is totally ramified, since the ramification index of any prime over P has to be greater than 1?.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of decomposition and inertia groups? Do you know that the inertia group of an unramified prime is cyclic?